# Processing each view /file in a folder

Tags: sublime-text-plugin

I have a number of files open in sublime, and do some processing on each one using the following in a TextCommand class:
my_views = self.view.window().views()

```
    for this_view in my_views:
        file_full_name = this_view.file_name()
        etc.
```

How do I do this when I have a folder open which contains all the files?  i.e. how do I get at the views in a folder?

Comment: You'll have to provide a bit more context. When you say an open folder in the sidebar with files, if those files aren't opened in ST, then they don't have a `view` associated to them (so you can't use any view related function). I guess you could also clarify what sort of processing you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for that - I see now they are not open.  The files contain text which has been created by OCR'ing a pdf document, and I am automating the correction of as many of the OCR errors as I can before manually fixing the rest.

Comment: You might have some success by writing a quick shell script to iterate through the files one by one and open them with `subl` using the `--command my_ocr_fix` switch (or whatever your command is called).